# Which other loss functions for hierarchical multi-label classification could I use?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, objective-functions, multi-label-classification

I am looking to try different loss functions for a hierarchical multi-label classification problem. So far, I have been training different models or submodels like multilayer perceptron (MLP) branch inside a bigger model which deals with different levels of classification, yielding a binary vector. I have been also using Binary Cross-Entropy (BCE) and summing all the losses existing in the model before backpropagating.

I am considering trying other losses like MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss and MultiLabelMarginLoss.

What other loss functions are worth trying? Hamming loss perhaps or a variation? Is it better to sum all the losses and backpropagate or do multiple backpropagations?

Answer (score 0):

**What hierarchical loss functions are worth trying**
There are a number of hierarchical loss functions that have been described (see  articles [#1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-010-0175-9) and [#2](https://Making%20Better%20Mistakes:%20Leveraging%20Class%20Hierarchies%20with%20Deep%20Networks)), such as [hierarchical win](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01062#:%7E:text=A%20hierarchical%20loss%20and%20its%20problems%20when%20classifying%20non%2Dhierarchically,-Cinna%20Wu%2C%20Mark&text=Failing%20to%20distinguish%20between%20a,are%20both%20breeds%20of%20dogs.) and [normalized LCA](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6247938).  The loss functions that you noted will not by themselves leverage the hierarchical information.